# Abstract Class with exception and Mockito testing in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, scalatest

I have an abstract class that looks like that:

```
abstract class ReadOnlyJsonFormat[T] extends RootJsonFormat[T] {
  final def write(obj: T): JsValue = throw DeserializationException("Unsupported operation")
}
```

The idea it simple: my subclasses implement a read-only JSON, I don't care about writing any object to JSON.

Now I'd like to use Mockito to test such class through a mock, where I can call the implemented method, and the following works:

```
"My nice test" should "raise an exception" in {
  val readOnlyJsonFormat = mock[ReadOnlyJsonFormat[Int]]
  intercept[DeserializationException] {when(readOnlyJsonFormat.write(1)).thenCallRealMethod()}

  val exc = intercept[DeserializationException] {
    readOnlyJsonFormat.write(1)
  }

  exc.getMessage must be ("Unsupported operation")
}
```

But since my method throws an exception when `.write()`, I'm forced to intercept such exception *when defining the behavior of the mock*, something that in Java was not necessary. Am I using Mockito in the wrong way? I tried using ScalaMock but I haven't found a way to call the real method on .